# Not enough replica available for query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 required but only 0 alive)

Tags: cassandra

I have 6 nodes in my cassandra cluster, all the nodes are up. My keyspace is set up as:

```
replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true
```

Doing a read from this cass cluster gives me the error:

```
java.io.IOException: Exception during execution of SELECT "colA", "colB", "colC", "colD" FROM "keyspacename"."tablename" WHERE token("colA") > ? AND token("colA") <= ?  LIMIT 1 ALLOW FILTERING: Not enough replica available for query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 required but only 0 alive)
```

All my nodes are up with a replication factor of 1.. then what is causing this problem?

Also I can cqlsh and do "select" and "insert" in this table.

Anyone know whats going on?

Comment: So you can do a select through cqlsh but not through the java driver? Can you give the output of nodetool status and also show the code which your driver uses to connect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SimpleStrategy: Use for a single data center only. If you ever intend more than one data center, use the NetworkTopologyStrategy.

Or try running the same query with Consistency ONE, ALL, ANY, QUORUM. I mean not with LOCAL_*

Comment: Yeaah I had to use NetworkTopologyStrategy since my cluster was in multiple datacenters. Thanks that fixed it!